# understanding this output for class in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class C
    a = 2
    puts a
    def initialize
        return b = 3
    end

 end

c = C.new
```

Output => 2

Hello, my question is why will the code above result in an output of 2? From my understanding initialize method is called when instance of the class is created (in this case c). Hence it should return an output of 3 when c is created.

Comment: class body is executable.

Comment: Also returning from the constructor doesn't change what `Class#new` will give you. You will always get an instance of that class back.

Comment: You are confusing `puts` and `return`. They do two fundamentally different things, and regardless, you can't `return` from a constructor. The value being assigned to `c` is an instance of `C`, *not* the value `2` or `3`. The `return b = 3` is doing absolutely nothing and being ignored, while the line `puts a` executes as it is encountered, *not* when you invoke `C.new`.

Comment: @meagar However consider this code `def test return b = 2 end ` `test` output result in 2 in this case. Why in this case the return, did print an output of 2 ?

Comment: @roppo First, it didn't *print* 2, it *returned* 2. If it printed anything, it's because you added a `puts`, or you're looking at return values in IRB. Second, because *it's not a constructor*. The return value of a constructor is completely ignored.

Comment: @meagar Thanks man I think I am starting to get the point.